# strange error in BS4. find_all() returns None

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, phantomjs

I am using BS4 and PhantomJS for scraping a website. Everything works fine on Mac but on Windows I got a strange error: `find_all()` returns `None`, but the elements exists!

My code:

```
def get_venues():
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = path)
    url=web+'#/racing'
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "wrapper")))
    finally:
        content=driver.page_source
        soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, "html5")
        driver.quit()

    b = soup.find(id='content').div
    print(b)
    c = b.ul(attrs={'class': 'main-list'})

    print(c)
```

and `c` is `None`, which should not be the case as `b` has:

```
</ul></div><ul class="main-list"><li><div class="collapsible R"><div class="icon race_code_R"></div><span>Thoroughbreds</span><div class="arrow_down_sign"></div></div><ul class="sub-list"><li class="venue cell"><a href="#/meetings/19197">
  <span class="location">Beaudesert</span>
  <div class="goto-sign"></div>
</a>
<a class="next-race" href="#/races/181880/exchange/win">
  <span class="time-left critical">-30m</span>
  <span class="number">R5</span>
</a>
</li><li class="venue cell"><a href="#/meetings/19199">
  <span class="location">Werribee</span>
  <div class="goto-sign"></div>
</a>
<a class="next-race" href="#/races/181900/exchange/win">
  <span class="time-left critical">-38s</span>
  <span class="number">R7</span>
</a>
</li><li c
```

Comment: Might be a problem with a parser used by `bs4` under-the-hood. What if you replace `html5` with `html.parser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with bringing code over from a mac to a windows machine is that the use slightly different utf-8 values when encoding files which can destroy your program if not caught so my best guess here (I'm no python expert) is that somewhere along the way from your mac to your pc a utf-8 character changed and now your entire program is being throne off one way to solve this is to reconstruct it from the ground up in a windows based IDE/Compiler/text editor hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

`b.ul` will work on windows

but `b.ul(attrs={'class': 'main-list'})` does not.

You will have to use,

```
c = b.find("ul",attrs={'class': 'main-list'})
```

And I don't have an answer to why this happens :-)

Hope that helps.

Comment: @tmac_balla just wondering - you say `find_all` doesn't work, But I don't see `find_all` in your code. All I see is `b = soup.find(id='content').div` could that be the concern? I am not sure - but just want to check - also if you can please add the page source so I can try things on windows, Thanks

Comment: @Mohsin neither find_all, nor find worked, nut the problem was in utf8 on Windows. I re-wrote all string values and it started working.